# Facing error while adding gitlab account to vscode

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

For the first time i'm using gitlab. Created a private project and added ssh key to the project. I have use GitLab workflow extension for connecting to my gitlab account. But not getting connected.

I have created private access token and tried connecting with it

```
2024-01-21T22:29:08:284 [error]: {
      "userMessage": "Request failed: Can't add GitLab account for https://gitlab.com. Check your instance URL and network connection.",
      "errorMessage": "request to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/personal_access_tokens/self failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 168.70.251.78:443",
      "stack": [
        "FetchError: request to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/personal_access_tokens/self failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 168.70.251.78:443",
        "    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (c:\\Users\\username\\.vscode\\extensions\\node_modules\\node-fetch\\lib\\index.js:1505:11)",
        "    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:525:35)",
        "    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:502:9)",
        "    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)",
        "    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)",
        "    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)"
      ]
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting. I checked the network connection and firewall settings. Everything is fine. I can even use my network to install extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gitlab version below 16.1, this is an expected error. Please update gitlab version to be greater than at least 15.5 to recover from this error.
Ref - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-vscode-extension#minimum-supported-version